# Proportional odds model with random effects

Tags: r, random-effects-model, ordered-logit, odds, frailty

I have a survival data set. I want to see the cluster specific variation, which we usually can do by using Cox proportional hazard model with frailty. But, the constant hazard ratio assumption of Cox PH may not be appropriate in some situations, in particular when the hazard rates of different individuals converge to the population mortality rate. In this situation, a proportional odds model may be more appropriate. But how can we perform a proportional odds model with random effect(frailty)? Any R package is available for this?

Comment: You can have a look here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2007.00960.x/abstract. 

I would be interested to know how you checked proportionality in the presence of a frailty term. Indeed, caution is needed when interpreting population hazards in the presence of heterogeneity in the population due to the "selection effect".

Comment: Have you given thought to performing a population level inference with robust standard errors to account for intracluster correlation and non-proportional hazards? With the use of sandwich based covariance measures, the model parameters are consistent estimates of the time-averaged hazard ratio.

Comment: Thanks Ocram. I have no clear answer about your question. I am trying to learn about this. Are there any book about proportional odds model in survival data? Suppose, mortality rate of disease group would approaches to the mortality rate of control group as time progresses. How can I capture it by Cox PH which consider hazard ratio become constant over time?

Comment: Dihan: Are you speaking about conditional (on the frailty) rates or about marginal rates? The distinction is indeed important. From Section 3.5 of the book by Duchateau and Janssen, it follows that non-proportionality at the marginal level can be explained by the presence of a frailty term at the conditional level.

Comment: Ocram: I am speaking about conditional rates. Basically, proportional odds model allows covariate-specific or subject-specific random effects, whereas general Cox PH frailty model only allows a cluster-specific frailty.

Comment: AdamO: Yes, I want to perform population level inference for intracluster correlation and non constant hazard ratio. Basically my concern, mortality rate of disease group would approaches to the mortality rate of control group as time progresses. I think in this situation Cox PH with frailty is not suitable for valid inference. I have no idea about your thought(sandwich based measure), can you explain it please?

Comment: @Dihan Non-proportionality is a big deal, but it's not clear how a proportional odds model would fix anything. There are a few methods to handle non-proportional hazards - restricted mean survival, p-rho-gamma functions, and lastly (and my preferred method) is to use a robust error estimator. Set Robust=T in the Cox model. You can look up the paper here https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1989.10478874

Answer (score 0):

In SAS 9.4 offical document, it provide an example Proportional Odds Model with Random Effects.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/statug/statug_glimmix_syntax01.htm

[image]

Comment: The R `ordinal` package allows for random effects.  Sometimes you have to specify a non-default numerical integration parameter to make it work properly.  I’d use 7-point quadrature.  The r `rmsb` package’s `blrm` function does Bayesian proportional odds models with random effects.  This gives an exact solution with no approximations such as what `ordinal` and `GLMMIX` use.